# slow json parsing while fetching data

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley, wordpress-rest-api

I am using WordPress rest API to fetch data and I am only fetching 10 posts at a time using volley.

[API Link](https://jamuitoday.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed&page=1)

When I request API in the browser it gives me a result under 6-7 seconds...

But my app takes more than 15 sec to show that 10 posts.

Sometimes it takes more than 1 minute to show the data.

I even added a parameter to get only 2 posts per page. But the response time is the same.

I am searching and modifying code from 2 days but can't get rid of it.

Here is the code:-

```
 private void jsonrequest(int pageNo) {
    JSON_URL = "https://jamuitoday.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed&page=" + pageNo;
    JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(JSON_URL, response -> {

        JSONObject jsonObject;
        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
            try {

                isLoading = true;
                isNewsLoaded = false;
                jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                News news = new News();

                //Get News Link
                String link = jsonObject.getString("link");
                news.setLink(link);

                //Set Date
                String date = jsonObject.getString("date");
                String d = date.substring(0, 10);
                int time = Integer.parseInt(date.substring(11, 13));
                if (time > 12) {
                    String ti = date.substring(13, 16);
                    String dt = d + "     " + (time - 12) + ti + " PM";
                    news.setdate(dt);
                } else {
                    String ti = date.substring(11, 16);
                    String dt = d + "     " + ti + " AM";
                    news.setdate(dt);
                }

                //Set Title
                JSONObject title = jsonObject.getJSONObject("title");
                String titleren = title.getString("rendered");
                news.setName(titleren);

                //Set Description
                SpannableString content = new SpannableString("Content");
                content.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, content.length(), 0);
                JSONObject desc = jsonObject.getJSONObject("content");
                String descSub = desc.getString("rendered");
                news.setDescription(String.valueOf(Html.fromHtml((descSub))));
                news.setAdImgUrl(descSub);


                // Set Image
                JSONObject img = new JSONObject(jsonObject.getString("_embedded"));
                JSONArray ttt = img.getJSONArray("wp:featuredmedia");
                String s = "";
                for (int t = 0; t < ttt.length(); t++) {
                    JSONObject obj = ttt.getJSONObject(t);
                    s = obj.getString("source_url");
                }
                news.setImage_url(s);

                listNews.add(news);
                

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        setuprecyclerview(listNews);
        isLoading = false;
        isNewsLoaded = true;
        
        pageNumber += 1;
        

        if (recyclerView.getLayoutManager() != null) {
            recyclerView.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(currentListPosition);
        }

        if (shimmerFrameLayout.isShimmerVisible()) {
            shimmerFrameLayout.stopShimmer();
            shimmerFrameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        if (swipyRefreshLayout.isRefreshing()) {
            swipyRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }

       

    }, error -> {

    });


    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
    requestQueue.add(request);


}
```

Any hack that can speed it up?

I'll implement SQLite to store data and show at app startup. So, the user can't feel the load time.

Comment: I would ask you to look into two things 1. [Android Paging library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging) as we can see you are using some kind of page. 2.I will recommend using [singleton pattern for volley](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLshdtb5UWjSraOqG1iZW-8mDkJXe3LSL0)

Comment: @SayokMajumder thanks. I tried the singleton pattern and it does improve the speed. But didn't understand what it does and how it works? and looking for tutorials on the paging library. Thanks, Buddy.

Comment: @SayokMajumder is there any way that can make my app use more internet speed instead of sharing with background system and apps.

Comment: Another thing I forgot to mention is check if any image is being loaded in the same thread or not. And just for testing purpose convert the JsonArrayRequest to a StringRequest and log the response string and check if the speed increases.

Comment: Karan check the android profiler to see how much internet is being used by your app. I dont think that there is any way you can increase the amount of internet assigned to the app.

Comment: No , as you can see setuprecyclerview method executing after end of for loop...Images load later when the it collects all the posts... And i am using glide to load images.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220090/discussion-between-karan-malhotra-and-sayok-majumder).